# Question Mark in JavaScript Source Map

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

The JS source maps for Kendo UI that I am using are failing to map properly in Chrome because of the question mark entry in the `sources` property. Chrome tries to load `js/src/js/?` which just returns the directory listing. After that the debugger points to `(index):9` for references to all minified scripts.

```
{ 
  "version": 3, 
  "file": "kendo.core.min.js", 
  "sources": [
    "?", 
    "kendo.core.js"
  ], 
  "names": [
    "f", 
    "define", 
    "$", 
    "undefined", 
    "..."
  ], 
  "mappings": "CAAA,SAAUA,EAAGC,QACTA,...", 
  "sourceRoot": "../../src/js/"
}
```

What does the question mark mean? And is it necessary or should I remove it to make the source maps function properly?